# PYTHON -- ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'playsound' when i am trying to import package

Tags: python, python-playsound

so this is the code i have been writing and saw it on a video tutorial on making a voice assistant, i copied the code exactly the same as the video but it just keeps popping up saying 'no module named playsound' but i have downloaded it in the command prompt window

below is my code

```
import os
import time
from playsound import playsound
import speech_recognition as sr 
from gtts import gTTS



def speak(text):
  tts = gTTS(text=text, lang="en")
  filename = "voice.mp3"
  tts.save(filename)
  playsound.playsound(filename)
  speak("hello danny")  `
```

any idea on what to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can install `playsound` package from `pip`

`pip install playsound`

After that in your code, you have to replace

`playsound.playsound(filename)` -> `playsound(filename)`

Comment: i have already installed playsound and changed the code but it is still displaying the same error. any more solutions??

Answer (score 0):

Most likely wrong version of py so I reckon that you have atleast python 2 installed which means that when you run pip install playsound, its installing into your python2 folder.

Try installing with

```
pip3 install playsound
```

Answer (score -1):

I was also facing the same issue. I uninstalled the playsound by using "pip uninstall playsound" , and installed playsound using the command "pip3 install playsound" .. it worked . Please try this  ..

Comment: This is already suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69753635/6045800)